# My data is not the same as user input and database

Tags: java, android

My data is not the same as user input and database. Data between age and gender is exchanged. How can this happen? What coding should I paste here?

[image]

Register Button:-

```
RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            SaveAccountInformation();
        }
    });
```

SaveAccountInformation Method:-

```
private void SaveAccountInformation()
{
    String usertype  = RegisterUserType.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String firstname = RegisterFirstName.getText().toString();
    String lastname = RegisterLastName.getText().toString();
    String gender = RegisterUserGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String age = RegisterAge.getText().toString();
    String phonenum = RegisterPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

String userid = databaseUser.push().getKey();
        User user = new User(userid, usertype, firstname, lastname, age, gender, phonenum);

        databaseUser.child(userid).setValue(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration has been successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Error occurred. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Constructor coding:-

```
public User(String userId, String userType, String userFirstName, String userLastName, String userGender, String userAge, String userContactNumber)
{
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
    this.userLastName = userLastName;
    this.userGender = userGender;
    this.userAge = userAge;
    this.userContactNumber = userContactNumber;
}
```

Comment: Did you swap the parameters in the constructor?  Or did you load them from the db in the wrong order?  As a side note, if you stored the variable as an integer in the db rather than a string it would likely have become a syntax error that's much easier to find.

Comment: No I didnt load them through the database. Then what should I do? I dont get it clear @GabeSechan

Comment: All the input is in the String type...

Comment: Paste your Model class

Comment: Check your `User` model class if your age and gender is in the right assigning place. E.g. `this.gender = gender`.

Comment: You must have swapped the order of the parameters. By the way, "occurred" has two R's in it.

Comment: @UmangBurman already paste it

Comment: @Tepits         this.userGender = userGender;

Comment: @DavidConrad I dont think so I swapped the parameters because I generate all the constructor and getter hmmm. Thanks for the error spelling.

Comment: In the code you showed before you had `new User(userid, usertype, firstname, lastname, age, gender, phonenum);` but now it looks like the constructor for `User` only takes three parameters?

Comment: @DavidConrad I cut the other because I cant paste all the code here, its too long.

Comment: show your code where you featch or set data from firebase

Comment: Please show all the relevant code - any constructor, getter, setter, or method calling any of the above. If we can't see your code, we can't help you.

Comment: @Jason I already put it in my question but I cant paste all the code here because its too long. In the coding, I only put the constructor and the getter only.

Comment: Or can we continue this conversation in a chat?

Comment: We can't see the code that calls your constructor. So we can't tell if the caller is passing the parameters in the correct order.

Comment: Just show us the actual constructor, and the database calls. We don't need to see all the getters. It's hard to tell, but the call to the constructor you showed before listed age before gender, and it looks like in your class you have gender before age.

Comment: Okay done edit the question...

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanks! I got it, I put the age first before gender...

Answer (score 1):

My error on this coding line: -

```
User user = new User(userid, usertype, firstname, lastname, gender, age, phonenum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor must be the same as the database range your class User

Comment: I already edit my question. As you can see in the image, the constructor same as in the database, right? :D